# How to download a image in magento admin panel from ordered items

Tags: php, magento, download

I have been trying to give a link to admin panel for downloading the product image ordered in sales > order > view. Now its done and I have given the link to download as

www.example.com/namespace/index(mycontroller)/download(myaction)/name/screen.jpg

Inside my controller's action I get the file name as parameter, and I knew the location where the file has been located. Now what should I need to make the image downloadable?

This is my controller action code:

```
public function downloadAction() {
    $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
    $file = Mage::getBaseDir(). DS . 'media' . DS . 'catalog' . DS . 'upload' . DS . $name;
    $content = readfile($file);
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($name, $content);
}
```

When I try to run the above code I get the following error.

Cannot send headers; headers already sent

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[readfile()](http://php.net/readfile) function reads a file and writes it to the **OUTPUT BUFFER** and returns the number of bytes read from the file. Here is the solution you may use to replace [readfile()](http://php.net/readfile) function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10938839/2720986

Comment: I removed readfile() function and it is working perfectly now. Thanks.